# Export to JAR excluding some additional files

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have project that builds class to bin directory. I have additional `ANT` builder that takes content of bin directory and puts to `proj_hug.jar`. But bin folder contains `*.properties` file that I don't wont include into JAR. How to solve this problem?

ANT script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project proj with libraries in sub-folder">
    <!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
    <target name="create_run_jar">
        <jar destfile="C:/Projects/proj/JAR/proj_hug.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="hug.projhugHandler"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value=". proj_hug_lib/RXTXcomm.jar proj_hug_lib/log4j.jar proj_hug_lib/hug.jar proj_hug_lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar"/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="C:/Projects/proj/bin">
            </fileset>
        </jar>
        <delete dir="C:/Projects/proj/JAR/proj_hug_lib"/>
        <mkdir dir="C:/Projects/proj/JAR/proj_hug_lib"/>
        <copy file="C:/Projects/proj/RXTXcomm.jar" todir="C:/Projects/proj/JAR/proj_hug_lib"/>
        <copy file="C:/Projects/proj/log4j.jar" todir="C:/Projects/proj/JAR/proj_hug_lib"/>
        <copy file="C:/Projects/proj/hug.jar" todir="C:/Projects/proj/JAR/proj_hug_lib"/>
        <copy file="C:/Projects/proj/commons-codec-1.5.jar" todir="C:/Projects/proj/JAR/proj_hug_lib"/>

    </target>
</project>
```

I have added in `<fileset>` like :

```
<fileset dir="C:/Projects/proj/bin">
        <include name="*.class"/>
        <exclude name="*.properties*"/>
</fileset>
```

But this makes things worse - no class files and no properties files at all in my JAR.

UPD:

If I make this:

```
<fileset dir="C:/Projects/proj/bin">
        <include name="**/*.class"/>
        <exclude name="**/*.properties*"/>
</fileset>
```

I have only META-INF in jar file.

If I do like:

```
 <fileset dir="C:/Projects/proj/bin">
            <include name="**/*.class"/>
    </fileset>
```

I have only META-INF in jar file.

If I do like:

```
<fileset dir="C:/Projects/proj/bin">
        <exclude name="**/*.properties*"/>
</fileset>
```

I have empty packages directoryes and META-INF in jar.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have `javac` task to compile the code into `<project home>/bin` directory.

Change your `fileset` to:

```
<fileset dir="C:/Projects/proj/bin">
    <include name="**/*.class"/>
    <exclude name="**/*.properties*"/>
</fileset>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does't solves problem. I have updated description with test result

Comment: javac task is missing. Please add javac task to compile the code into C:/Projects/proj/bin directory.

Comment: You should really break up some of the tasks into separate targets, like clean, compile and jar.  It makes the process easier to build and  reuse the targets potentially.